# create if not exists... with multiple properties (and unique ID)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First, sorry for my pretty bad english, i'm French :p

I'm currently switching from MySQL to Neo4j and i have a little question about my scripts.

I have artists and music albums; each of them linked (if needed) as (artist)-[:OWNS]->(album).

Now i develop the API for updating the information and i have a little "bug" for this :

How can i get an existing node and create it if not exist ?

For another part, i'm doing like that :

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id='83cac821-1607-49a3-e124-07431ef375ce' MERGE (c:Country {name:'France'}) CREATE UNIQUE (u)-[:FROM]->(c) RETURN u,c;
```

So, if the country "France" already exists, neo4j will not create a second one... Perfect 'cause my countries haven't ID's...

But for artists and albums, i need an unique identifier; and i can't create my request :

```
MATCH (ar:Artist) WHERE ar.id='83cac821-1607-49a3-e124-07431ef375ce' MERGE (al:Album {name:'Title01', id:'31efc821-1607-49a3-e124-074383ca75ce'}) CREATE UNIQUE (ar)-[:OWNS]->(al) RETURN ar,al;
```

In this way, i need to know the album'ID (and in my API, i don't !). In fact, i need Neo4j get the album "Title01" if exist, and create (with a fresh new ID) if not. In my exemple, if i don't give the ID, it can get the album if exist; but if not, it will create a new one without ID... And if i send an ID, neo4j will never get it (cause the title's already exist but not with this particular ID).

(Before, in Mysql i was using multiple requests : 1° search if album exist. If yes, return ID; if not create with new one and return ID. 2° the same for artist. 3° create link between them...)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MERGE` command can be extended with `ON MATCH` and `ON CREATE`, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-merge.html#_use_on_create_and_on_match. I guess you have to something like

```
MATCH (ar:Artist) WHERE ar.id='83cac821-1607-49a3-e124-07431ef375ce'
MERGE (al:Album {name:'Title01'})
ON CREATE SET al.id = '31efc821-1607-49a3-e124-074383ca75ce'
CREATE UNIQUE (ar)-[:OWNS]->(al) RETURN ar,al
```

Comment: Be aware that MERGE may change: 

"MERGE is a new addition and a provisional feature of Cypher. Its scope and syntax are subject to change. Therefore, please be aware that you may need to change queries that use MERGE in the future."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page that shows how to create a node if it doesn't exist: [Link](http://ghost.lelandcope.com/2014/01/24/neo4j-2-0-create-object-if-it-doesnt-exist/)